# Where to ask a question considering Market Technical Analysis?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

What [Stack Exchange site](https://stackexchange.com/sites) is most suitable to ask a question considering [Market Technical Analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technical_analysis)? Programming related (e.g. MetaTrader) and non-programming related (theory, etc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can visit [Quantitative Finance Stack Exchange](https://quant.stackexchange.com/)  which was an Area 51 proposal when this post was written but is now a graduated Stack Exchange site.

Answer (score 2):

Since there is no specific Q&A on StackExchange for market technical analysis, it depends on the nature of each question.

Strictly programming-related ones would suit [StackOverflow](http://www.stackoverflow.com). For theory, provided the focus is on numerical methods or you are able to formulate it as such, try [Statistical Analysis](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) or a more general [Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 2):

Until the [Quantitative Finance](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/117/quantitative-finance) stack is up and running, you might try [Personal Finance and Money](https://money.stackexchange.com/).